# express app.use middle layer for authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, redis

I'm trying to benefit from middle layer of `app.use` for authentication. I'm new to this, and I read about it somewhere without an example.

I'm not using `app.use` for authentication at the moment but I'd like to use if it makes sense, I've a token based authentication in place, upon request, I perform some checks, and then route it to the destination module.

I don't want to use any 3rd party modules for authentication, as I've my own token generation and verification routines. Question is how do I employ it within the following, as the authentication system I've is asynchronous procedure (I've redis handling tokens). I can't get my head around calling my async process from `app.use` and then calling `next` after I finish with success and then what about failure?.

```
app.use(function(request, response, next){
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much have what you want there in that you've created a middleware function, except you may want to only 'use' it sometimes.  As such, app.use would only be appropriate if you want to use token parsing on every request that hits your server.  You're likely to have some routes you want to require a token and others that can be public to anyone, logged in or not.

The piece you may be missing is you can assign a name to the function and apply it to certain routes, but not others.  You can do this by naming the middleware function.

```
var tokenMiddlewareFn = function(req, res, next) {
    // do stuff
    next();
}
```

Then when you want to apply it:

```
app.get('/protected', tokenMiddlewareFn, function(req, res, next) {
   // do stuff
}
```

I typically place all of my middleware functions in a directory, each as their own files.  Besides checking for authentication tokens, an example of a middleware function that I've found helpful is parsing pagination query string parameters since many routes will use want to parse the request for such params in the same manner. Following that style for authentication purposes, you could put a file, say require-auth.js, in the middleware directory that looks like:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    var token = req.header('X-App-Auth');

    // do what you want with token...perhaps attaching some data to the 
    // request after you perform the redis lookup
    req.userId = what you find in redis

    next();
}
```

Then when routing a request to a protected place and want to require a token you can do something like:

```
var requireAuth = require('path/to/middleware/require-auth');

app.get('/protected', requireAuth, function(req, res, next) {
    // require auth was run before getting here and
    // you now can access req.userId
});

app.get('/unprotected', function(req, res, next) {
   // requireAuth was never run...
}
```

Try throwing in some console.logs to see for yourself how middleware works.  You could do something like:

```
var a = function(req, res, next) { 
    console.log("...executing a");
    next();
}

var b = function(req, res, next) { 
    console.log("...executing b"); 
    next();
}

var c = function(req, res, next) { 
    console.log("...executing c"); 
    next();
}

app.use(c);

app.get('/', a, b, function(req, res, next) {
    // a, b, and c were already executed in the order of c a b
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    // just c was run
});
```

Hope that helps,

Craig

Comment: I'm studying your answer, however, I've a weird issue with `app.use`, it's NOT called on all of the routes, this is my first time with it, I placed a `console` statement inside app.use function and it only executes on unspecified routes and routes defined after, not sure how to use it in the right way? I've actually submodules that defines their own routes etc.

Comment: @user2727195 order matters.  That is if you catch a route via app.get(...) before an app.use(...) then it will never get run assuming you don't call next() in the app.get(...)

Comment: @user2727195 Think of request handling as a pipeline and middleware functions as pipes.  You can run the request through as many pipes you want in whatever order you want, but once you send the response, the request will not go through any more pipes.

Comment: this clears up. `once you send the response, the request will not go through any more pipes.` now let me put my setup and it's different from the typical setups out there, think of it several "Cores", several module (and I don't mean node module), I think core is the right word, or let's say I've several nodejs apps (not literally) within one app, one of them is the "Admin Core"

Comment: "Shell Core" instantiates the cores and dispatches the `app` to all those cores, each core defines their own routes (based on path, /users/routes,  like /admin/routes, /products/routes etc.) and each core may define their own `app.use`, admin core needs authentication so in it's middle layer, I take care of that, all I can think of it's like check if requested path is really under '/admin' otherwise I `next()` it, any other thoughts.

Comment: You may disagree with spreading routes definition across different cores, I've very high decoupling and reusability going on in here, as long as routes are defined within their path, all good, `app.use` got my confused a bit since there could be uses further down the road in other cores, so just wanted to be really careful about it.

Comment: `request.url` is the only candidate I see to check string based index of `'/admin/routes'`, to dispatch the authentication process and `next()` it if not, any thoughts

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking across all the comments! It seems there's enough in there that you're asking a different question now! I'd suggest making a new post and providing some code. 

If my response cleared up how app.use and middleware works, I'd appreciate you marking my answer as correct =)

Comment: I like the approach that @cpentra1 takes, named middleware are very compose-able.  This is every similar to how I've written the API for our [stormpath-sdk-express](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-express) module.  I took it a little further and provided functions that you can use to configure instances of the named middleware.  P.S. you might want to check out [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you said you didn't want to use 3rd party modules, the go-to solution for Node/Express authentication is [Passport](http://passportjs.org/). Don't dismiss it. It is a pluggable authentication system that will let you use a bunch of different providers like Facebook, Google, Twitter etc. (all packaged as independent modules), but the one you care about is [Passport Local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local). That lets you define your own authentication strategy (which seems to be what you want). Have a look at the tutorial [Authenticating Node.js Applications With Passport](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619). It uses Passport Local to implement a custom strategy.

Comment: Hi Alex, actually I've my own authentication system, I've a table of user accounts with emails and passwords, I verify them from the database, and generate authTokens, store them in redis. next time the request comes I check it against the redis storage. Facebook, Google, Twitter authentication are out of the scope. It's a custom authentication and want to keep control over verification and generation in my hands.

Comment: And the local authentication strategy is exactly for situations where you have your own user names/passwords. But I understand if you really want to handle everything that it isn't the right solution. The other thing I would say is that you should read the code for how it should be done. If you mess up authentication, we'll be reading about you in all the tech blogs ;-)